# How do you make a dummy variable? in R

Tags: r

```
sex
religion (Christian, Catholic, Islam)

       female sexmale   Christian   Catholic  Islam
1          0       1        0          1        0
2          0       1        1          0        0
3          1       0        1          0        0 
4          1       0        0          0        1 
5          0       1        0          1        0
```

I think the total number of cases is six.
The question is how to code for using it as a dummy variable for linear regression.

Comment: Assuming `1` means "this row relates to an experimental unit that has the attribute" and `0` the opposite (or vice versa), then you already have defined dummy variables.  You can use either `female` or `sexmale` (but not both) and/or two from `Christian`, `Catholic` and `Islam` as covariates in a model.  In a linear regression you'd probably need another continuous term in the model.  You mention "cases" but don't define what one is.  Logistic regression might be more appropriate than linear regression if you are modelling the incidence of cases.

Comment: "I think the total number of cases is six" -- The number 6 seems to not occur in your data. I don't know what you are referring to. "The question is how to code for using it as a dummy variable for linear regression." -- I don't know what "it" refers to. You haven't clearly explained what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `dummy_cols()` function from `fastDummies` package:

```
# install.packages("fastDummies")
library(fastDummies)
df <- data.frame(numbers = 1:5,
                 sex  = c("female", "female", "male", "male", "female"),
                 religion = c("Catholic", "Christian", "Christian", "Islam", "Catholic"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


dummy_cols(df)

# Output:
> dummy_cols(df)
  numbers    sex  religion sex_female sex_male religion_Catholic religion_Christian religion_Islam
1       1 female  Catholic          1        0                 1                  0              0
2       2 female Christian          1        0                 0                  1              0
3       3   male Christian          0        1                 0                  1              0
4       4   male     Islam          0        1                 0                  0              1
5       5 female  Catholic          1        0                 1                  0              0
```

Comment: This seems to be essentially what they already have (albeit packaged a bit nicer). What I *guess* they want is a new factor with 2x3 = 6 levels so that e.g. a female Catholic would be 1 level, a male Catholic another, a female Christian a third, etc.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Only OP can clarify. I just can't think of any other way that the number 6 could enter into the problem.